# What should type of T support so List<T> can do OrderBy

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

Why sometimes List collections doesn't support OrderBy or ToList() or other methods and Intellisence wouldn't even show them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any type that implements the `IEnumerable<T>` interface can be used with the LINQ extension methods: `OrderBy`, `ToList` etc. `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, and so does almost every other generic collection that you're likely to encounter.

However, because LINQ is primarily implemented using extension methods, you'll need to include a `using System.Linq` directive at the top of your code file. If you don't have `using System.Linq` then the LINQ extensions aren't going to appear in intellisense etc.